# Getting unicode results in MailChimp oauth2 token creation

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, mailchimp

I have generated the access code by using https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/authorize API. But when I try to create the token using https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token, I'm getting unicode result like this.

> (?M?? ?0F?UJ?N?NQ? %`??'
>   "?????nb??f=?&9????i'f??]?~j*$??W??Reg??_T1-???;?oc)

```
qryStr = {"client_secret":"**********","grant_type":"authorization_code","redirect_uri":"https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fverifymailchimp.sas","client_id":"********","code":"*************"}

HttpURLConnection connection = null;
try
{
    URL reqURL = new URL("https://login.mailchimp.com/oauth2/token");

    connection = (HttpURLConnection) reqURL.openConnection();
    connection.setConnectTimeout(3000); // 3 seconds
    connection.setReadTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds
    connection.setUseCaches(false);
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8"); 
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //No I18N
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", "" + Integer.toString(qryStr.getBytes().length)); //No I18N
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    OutputStream os = null;
    try
    {
        os = connection.getOutputStream();
        os.write(qryStr.getBytes(CHARSET));
    }
    finally
    {
        try{os.close();}catch(Exception e){}
    }
    int resCode = connection.getResponseCode();
    boolean success = (resCode >= 200 && resCode < 300);


    InputStream is = success ? connection.getInputStream() : connection.getErrorStream();
    if (is == null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    String contentStr = null;
    try
    {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(is, CHARSET);
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        char[] bytes = new char[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = reader.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) > 0)
        {
            buffer.append(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        contentStr = buffer.toString();//?M??   ?0F?UJ?N?NQ? %`??' "?????nb??f=?&9????i'f??]?~j*$??W??Reg??_T1-???;?oc
    }
    finally
    {
        try{is.close();}catch(Exception e){}
    }
}
```

Can anyone please tell the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the cause of this case. An access code is valid for 30 seconds. Need to generate the token before the expiry. If they conveyed the proper error message, we can able to sort out the problem without any confusion :(